# Nested fixed position

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem with my html / CSS pattern.

I have a fixed top menu (height: 110px). In this fixed menu, I'm trying to create a cart that only displays on hover.
For that purpose, I'm using a div that shows only when the cursor is hover.

It works for Firefox and Chrome. The div named "hover-content" is out of the flow.
But for Safari, it doesn't work as expected. The div shows but inside the top menu, not out of the flow.

[image: Firefox's behavior]

[image: Safari's behavior]

Do you have any idea how i could solve this problem on Safari?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Singertwist

```css
.menu-top-commander {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 110px;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte:first-child {
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #CE3734;
  border-right: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte .menu-top-commander-texte-lien {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte p a {
  color: #000000;
}

.menu-top-commander-smaller {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 65px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte-lien:last-child {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#hover-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  transform: translate(-200px, 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte-lien:last-child:hover #hover-content {
  display: block;
}

.menu-top-commander-texte-lien:last-child img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .menu-top-commander {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .menu-top-commander-texte:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: none;
  }
  .menu-top-commander-texte {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .menu-top-commander-texte p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .menu-top-commander-texte-lien:last-child {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-top-commander">
  <div class="menu-top-commander-texte">Menu</div>
  <div class="menu-top-commander-texte">
    <div class="menu-top-commander-texte-lien">
      <p><a href="">Plats</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-top-commander-texte-lien">
      <p><a href="">A-Côtés</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-top-commander-texte-lien">
      <p><a href="">Boissons</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-top-commander-texte-lien">
      <p><a href="">Desserts</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-top-commander-texte-lien">
      <p>
        <a href=""><img src="img/icones/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping cart"></a>
      </p>
      <div id="hover-content">
        Content.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As in the code example there is no content that could overlap it, it is hard to reconstruct for us. Could you maybe add that? Anyways, is your menu at the very bottom of your body? Right before `</body>`? Because usually browsers tend to put things later in the html over things that came before them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
So, I found a solution. Actually, the problem with Safari was the two fixed position for the nested div.
The first div (parent div) has a fixed position, and the child div (which displays on hover) has also a fixed position.

For the first div (parent div), I tried a sticky position, and for the second div (child div), I used a fixed position.

And it works for Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Thank you for your help,

Singerwist